# How do i Bulk Load AWS Neptune using a Lambda?

Tags: httprequest, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I'm trying to attempt bulk loading Neptune using the loader endpoint, and Apache HTTP client by making the POST call like below.

```
My lambda is in the same VPC as Neptune and has the same sub-nets and Security group as well.

However i'm seeing : 

`org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: cluster-endpoint-url:8182 failed to respond`
```

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String requestBodyJSON = objectMapper
        .writeValueAsString(values);

CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://endpont:8182/loader");
log.info("Initiated HTTP Client ");
HttpEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(requestBodyJSON, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
log.info("RESPONSE is "+ response2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely issue is the use of `http://` versus `https://`.  Neptune does not allow for non-SSL/TLS connections.  Also check your security group configuration.  The security group for Neptune should be allowing inbound traffic from the subnets or the security group used by the Lambda function.

Comment: Thanks for the response, using https and adding the Security group used by lambda fixed this !